# Ideals / Direct sum decomposition

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $u = (u_1 , \ldots , u_n ) \in \mathbb{A}^n$. Let $I$ be the ideal of $A = \mathbb{C}[x_1 , \ldots x_n ]$ generated by the elements $x_1 - u_1 , \ldots , x_n - u_n$.

(i) Show that as a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space, $A = \mathbb{C} \oplus I$.

(ii) Show that $A/I$ is a field.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Try defining a ring homomorphism $\mathbb C[x_1, \ldots, x_n] \to \mathbb C$ by $x_i \mapsto u_i$.  Then think about what the kernel of this homomorphism is.